# Does LINQ to XML ignore includes from a DTD?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, dtd, mathml

I'm using the MathML DTD for parsing MathML using `System.Xml.Linq.` While the ordinary MathML stuff gets recognized fine, the `MMLEXTRA` include in the DTD gets ignored and I get errors. Here's the code I'm using:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mathML))
  {
    try
    {
      const string preamble =
          "<!DOCTYPE mml:math PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN\"\n" +
           "\"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd\" [\n" +
           "<!ENTITY % MATHML.prefixed \"INCLUDE\">\n" +
           "<!ENTITY % MATHML.prefix \"mml\"> \n" +
         "]>";
      var parsed = Parser.Parse(preamble + Environment.NewLine + mathML);
      textEditor.Text = printed;
      lblStatus.Caption = "MathML successfully translated.";
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      lblStatus.Caption = "Cannot translate text. " + e.Message;
    }
  }
```

The parser simply does `XDocument.Load()`. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Kirk `Parser` is just a component that basically does `XDocument.Load`. The assumption is that this call would directly resolve all the MathML references, but it does not.

Answer (score 6):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/ea032ff4-b3e5-45ba-94a0-1cc4d5d8184d/)

> Entities in DTDs are inherently not secure. It is possible for a
>   malicious XML document that contains a DTD to cause the parser to use
>   all memory and CPU time, causing a denial of service attack.
>   Therefore, in LINQ to XML, DTD processing is turned off by default.
>   You should not accept DTDs from untrusted sources.
>
> However, to enable it you should use [XDocumentType class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

A couple of possible solutions:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("filename"), settings);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Or maybe:

```
 XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(new XDocumentType("Books",null,"Books.dtd", null),new XElement("Book"));
```

All information is from that same [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/ea032ff4-b3e5-45ba-94a0-1cc4d5d8184d/)

Comment: Awesome! That totally does it for me. Phew! 50 rep points spent, but my product is safe :) Thanks!

Comment: The quoted answer contradicts the current MS documentation, that states “When a document contains entity references that are defined in a DTD, the references are expanded upon creation of the XML tree” : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1
Maybe there was a design change decision some time in these 9 years.